# Нужна ли запятая перед "к кому"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Он скажет, к кому идти с вашей проблемой.*

Comment: В первую очередь необходима точка.

Answer (score 2):

*Он скажет (что?), к кому идти с вашей проблемой.*

А почему возникли сомнения? Сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая разделяет простые предложения в сложном.

Comment: Сомнения могут быть вызваны "сочетанием со значением частицы". На форуме недавно поднимался такой же вопрос.

Comment: @БотБотович вы серьезно? Ну какое тут может быть "сочетание со значением"? Да и вопрос уровня пятого класса, а вы какие-то дискуссионные академические дебри хотите приплести.

Comment: Не верите — спросите у Sharon. Она ответ на подобный вопрос и публиковала.

Comment: Это Вы что-то не поняли  в ответе  Sharon,  не вижу здесь никакого сочетания со значением частицы, здесь всё элементарно. Не подскажете ссылочку на тот ответ ?